# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter

Declaration:

```
bool switchVariable = true;
```

Code section:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
switchVariable = (prefs.getBool('switchVariable') ?? true);
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

This error, when you select the link to the offending code, highlights this specifically:

```
*switchVariable* = (prefs.getBool('switchVariable') ?? true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool switchVariable = (prefs.getBool('switchVariable') ?? true);
```

Try to add bool infront of switchVariable

A working codesnippet of SharedPreferences:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getSwitchValues();
  }

  bool _isSwitched;
    getSwitchValues() async {
        _isSwitched = await getSwitchState();

        setState(() {_isSwitched = _isSwitched});
      }  



//Gets initialized when the switch is switched
      Future<bool> saveSwitchState(bool value) async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        //Set the bool value of switchState the switch
        prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
        print('Switch Value saved $value');

    return prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
  }

  Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Get's the value from prefs
    bool _isSwitched = prefs.getBool("switchState");
    print(_isSwitched);
    return _isSwitched;
  }
```

The switch:

```
Switch(
                        value: _isSwitched ?? false,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _isSwitched = value;

                            saveSwitchState(value);
                            print('Saved state is $_isSwitched');

                          });
                        },
                        activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                        activeColor: Colors.green,
                      ),
```

Comment: Thanks, NXS.   When I add "bool" in front of the offending line, I get an error in logic, because switchVariable has already been declared as a bool at the start.   It needs to remain a global variable as it is accessed in different modules.  I cannot declare it again like this.   Thank you for the input though.

Comment: Also, I have hundreds of these lines of code using shared preference, previously without any issues at all.   If I have to write an entire app every time I want to use shared preferences then there is legitimately no reason to ever use shared preferences.  I should just be able to get instance, getValues, setValues.   It has always worked like this, single lines of code for each requirement.   It's just now, with no changes other than an update to flutter and the shared-preferences plugin, that it seems to have broken logic.

Comment: @Bisclavret If you want it to be accessed in different modules you should define it as "static". And oh, okay so it could also just be the update... Well, I'm not an expert but I hope you can get it solved!